# IBDesignable class drawing UIImage not displaying in storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, storyboard

I have been designing a custom controller in XCode which draws itself based upon which state it is in. In one state the controller displays an image by calling `myImage?.draw(in: rect)` within the overwritten `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function.

**The image displays in the app correctly, but does not in the storyboard.** To illustrate this I added a Bezier ring within the same draw function, which displays in both the app and the storyboard:

[Controller as displayed in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Lbv.png)

[Controller as displayed in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI0M6.png)

Having investigated the problem, I believe it may be to do with the fact that the image is an optional. Explicitly unwrapping it, however, (i.e calling `myImage!.draw(in: rect)` causes the storyboard auto-layout to crash:

```
error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for SermonViewController (1zk-bD-8it): The agent crashed
```

I've stripped down the full implementation of the class :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DownloadIndicatorControl: UIView {

    let requestDownloadImage = UIImage(named: "requestDownloadImage")
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 3.0
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // Draw Image
        requestDownloadImage?.draw(in: rect)

        // Draw ring around image
        let radius: CGFloat = fmin(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) / 2 - lineWidth / 2
        let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2, y: self.bounds.size.height / 2)
        let disk: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        disk.lineWidth = lineWidth
        disk.addArc(withCenter: center,
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2),
                    endAngle: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi - Double.pi/2),
                    clockwise: true)
        disk.stroke()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I can do to make the image display in storyboard and is there any way to explicitly unwrap the image without crashing storyboard constantly?

Answer (score 8):

UIImage(named:) method uses main bundle but Interface Builder load resources in different way.

Try this:

UIImage(named:in:compatibleWith:)

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DownloadIndicatorControl: UIView {

var requestDownloadImage: UIImage?
let lineWidth: CGFloat = 3.0

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    // Draw Image
    requestDownloadImage?.draw(in: rect)

    // Draw ring around image
    let radius: CGFloat = fmin(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) / 2 - lineWidth / 2
    let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2, y: self.bounds.size.height / 2)
    let disk: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    disk.lineWidth = lineWidth
    disk.addArc(withCenter: center,
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2),
                endAngle: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi - Double.pi/2),
                clockwise: true)
    disk.stroke()
}

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    self.setup()
}

internal func setup() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: DownloadIndicatorControl.self)
    requestDownloadImage = UIImage(named: "download", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
}
}
```

[image]